# Selenium WebDriver FindElements do not return enough values

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have setup a class with properties get value from WebDriver.FindElements().

```
    public IList<IWebElement> ListObjectElements
    {
        get
        {
            var container = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("objects"));
            return container.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'id_')]"));
        }
    }
```

I also implemented test case to test Add New function.

All steps ran success. When I tried to get the return of new list after Add New, it missed 1 item.

I set a break point to watch value. The property ListObjectElements has 10 items, but the return newList only has 9.

```
    var newList = clientpage.ListObjectElements;

    return newList;
```

If I add a Thread.Sleep(), the return newList has 10 items same as the property ListObjectElements.

How could I get the exactly results without using Thread.Sleep()?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Probably the last item wasn't loaded properly when the required elements were accessed. Please try by using a bigger implicit wait time so that all the elements are accounted for.

Comment: The property has all elements I need (10 items), but the variable assigned from property only has 9 items.

I also set implicit wait 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the site you're automating adds the elements representing the objects dynamically to the DOM, and that your code is then losing the race condition that you execute `FindElements` before the elements are actually added to the DOM. You'll need to implement some sort of wait in your code. You might be able to leverage the `WebDriverWait` construct, the .NET implementation of which is available in the `WebDriver.Support` assembly. The construct could be used in a manner similar to the following:

```
// Assumes 'driver' is a valid IWebDriver instance.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
{
    return clientPage.ListObjectElements.Count > 9;
});
```

Putting this in a more concrete context in your test case would look something like this, depending on your architecture and desires:

```
// Assume that the element you click on to add a new element
// is stored in the variable 'element', and your IWebDriver
// variable is 'driver'.
int originalCount = clientPage.ListObjectElements.Count;
element.Click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
{
    return clientPage.ListObjectElements.Count > originalCount;
});

return clientPage.ListObjectElements;
```

Comment: I found the problem. It's because of ordered list after adding a new item. I should aware that. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: This is still very useful for many rookie Selenium folks who might be trying to get ajax search result rows that are going to appear on the page only after the xhr request is done, making the Wait API the only choice.